# Convert PHP file to Word doc and to open it in browser

Tags: php, phpword

I like to convert my PHP file to Word document and I used this code

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=SaveAsWordDoc.doc");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">
<title>Saves as a Word Doc</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Header</h1>
  This text can be seen in word
<ul>
<li>List 1</li>
<li>List 2</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly, it prompting me to open/save the document instead of rendering it like a normal webpage. But I need to open the same page in browser too.

Is there any way to open a PHP page in web browser and also to make it save as word doc. If possible, give me code which prompting save as Word doc by clicking a button.

Comment: `give me teh codezzzzz`....

Comment: Why escape the quotes on the meta tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it a parameter when you wish to download it:

```
<?php
if( $_GET['action'] == 'download' ) {
  header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=SaveAsWordDoc.doc");
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<? } ?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">
<title>Saves as a Word Doc</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Header</h1>
  This text can be seen in word
<ul>
<li>List 1</li>
<li>List 2</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Then have a link that passed `file.php?action=download`

Comment: Is an HTML document a valid Word document? (I expect it will work, but that's a different question).

Comment: I did not consider or address the correctness of the format.